# PDO дублирует результаты в строке, с цифровыми и строковыми индексами

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Делаю выборку из таблицы:

```
$res = $mysql->prepare('SELECT id, phoneNumber, serialNum
                        FROM modemsInfo
                       ');
$res->execute();
$arr = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);

echo '<br>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Получаю:

```
Array
(
    [139] => Array
        (
            [phoneNumber] => +71111111111
            [1] => +71111111111
            [serialNum] => 000001
            [2] => 000001
        )

    [140] => Array
        (
            [phoneNumber] => +72222222222
            [1] => +72222222222
            [serialNum] => 000000
            [2] => 000000
        )

)
```

А ожидал это:

```
Array
(
    [139] => Array
        (
            [phoneNumber] => +71111111111
            [serialNum] => 000001
        )

    [140] => Array
        (
            [phoneNumber] => +72222222222
            [serialNum] => 000000
        )

)
```

Не догоню, где я ошибся? Если верить https://phpfaq.ru/pdo/fetch, то мои ожидания должны были сработать

Comment: PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE по-умолчанию PDO::FETCH_BOTH, результат выглядит полностью ожидаемым для меня.

Comment: @Мелкий сидел думал что это значит)
 Дошло. Поменял PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC. все заработало. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию PDO испльзует режим `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, который возвращает массив, индексированный как именами столбцов результирующего набора, так и их номерами (начиная с 0).

Чтобы получить только ассоциативные индексы, надо использовать режим `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Если надо его объединить с другим режимом, то указать через битовое "или", например

```
$arr = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Но проще всего установить желаемый режим по умолчанию сразу при соединении, с помощью настройки `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE`.

Answer (score -4):

Попробуйте так

```
$res = $mysql->prepare('SELECT id, phoneNumber, serialNum
                    FROM modemsInfo
                   ');
$res->execute();
$arr = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<br>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, **не пишите ответ**, если не поняли вопроса

Comment: Я написал вполне рабочий код так как хотел задающий вопрос соучастник. И это ответ! Сперва проверьте код прежде чем минусовать правильные ответы

Comment: Он же хотел получить ассоциативный массив FETCH_ASSOC вот и оно

Comment: Верните мне мои баллы

Comment: Нет, задающий вопрос участник хотел не это. Вам не хватает квалификации понять суть вопроса, и поэтому вы не должны на него отвечать

Comment: А как вы то поняли что он хотел. И где можно жалобу написать на вас

Comment: Вы можете удалить ответ, тогда репутация восстановится